# Пустой атрибут "soapAction" в функции WSDL

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

Имеется веб-сервис со следующим WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://fer2.klab/notify" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://fer2.klab/notify" targetNamespace="http://fer2.klab/notify">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:er="http://fer2.klab/notify" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://fer2.klab/notify">
    <xs:element name="ServiceRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="HL7message" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="ServiceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="response" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="ServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ServiceResponse" name="ServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="ServiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:ServiceRequest" name="ServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="NotifyPort">
    <wsdl:operation name="Service">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:ServiceRequest" name="ServiceRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:ServiceResponse" name="ServiceResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="NotifyPortSoap11" type="tns:NotifyPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Service">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="ServiceRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="ServiceResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="NotifyPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:NotifyPortSoap11" name="NotifyPortSoap11">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.101:8080/fer2-0.0.1/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Есть endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class NotifyEndPoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URL = "http://fer2.klab/notify";

    @Autowired
    MainController mainController;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URL, localPart = "ServiceRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ServiceResponse send(@RequestPayload ServiceRequest hlMessage){
        System.out.println("notify method");
        Object resp = mainController.notify(null, "", hlMessage.getHL7Message());
        ServiceResponse sr = new ServiceResponse();
        if (resp != null){
            sr.setResponse(resp.toString());
        }
        else{
            sr.setResponse("null");
        }

        return sr;
    }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<sws:annotation-driven />

<bean id="notify" name="notify" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
        <!--<property name="createSoap12Binding" value="true" />-->
        <property name="portTypeName" value="NotifyPort" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/ws" />
        <property name="schema">
            <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
                <property name="xsd" value="notify.xsd" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://fer2.klab/notify" />
        <property name="soapActions">
            <props>
                <prop key="http://fer2.klab/notify/ws/ServiceRequest">ServiceRequest</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

application-config.xml:

```
<bean class="klab.backend.utils.MainConfig" id="mainConfig">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/main.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/build.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="true"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.JacksonView2HttpMessageConverter">

            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="klab.backend.utils.json.KJsonMapper">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<context:component-scan base-package="klab.fer2"/>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator"/>
</bean>

<bean class="klab.backend.controller.base.DefaultController"/>

<bean name="CorsFilter" class="klab.backend.filter.CorsFilter"/>
```

Почему при генерации WSDL атрибут `soapAction` у операции `Service` пустой?

При выполнении SOAP-запроса на URL http://192.168.1.101:8080/fer2-0.0.1/ws со следующим содержимым:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:not="http://fer2.klab/notify">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <not:ServiceRequest>
         <not:HL7message>hdfghdfghdfgh</not:HL7message>
      </not:ServiceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

в логах появляется ошибка

```
 org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointNotFound- No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://fer2.klab/notify}ServiceRequest]
```

Comment: `<sws:annotation-driven />` включен?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov нет. Добавили в dispatcher-servlet.xml, не помогло.

Comment: Где определён сервлет с именем `dispatcher`? Ты определяешь сканирование пакетов в общем конфиге. Далее поднимается сервлет `dispatcher` и там уже включаются аннотации для веб-сервисов, но там не включается сканирование пакетов. Как spring определяет, что твой ендпоинт относится именно к сервлету `dispatcher` а не к какому-то другому? По какому адресу доступна wsdl?

Answer (score 1):

Почему `SoapAction` пустой? - потому что ты нигде его не указал. Собственно это обычный http-заголовок. В твоём же случае ты используешь маршрутизацию по паре (пространство имён корневого элемента, имя корневого элемента).

Так как ты привел только части своих конфигов, то исхожу из того, что ты используешь `JAXB` и он правильно настроен. Класс-ендпоинт настроен правильно. Следовательно причина только одна. Spring не может его найти. Вероятно ты не указал пакет для сканирования. Добавь в свой конфиг сервиса следующие строки:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="пакет.где.лежит.ендпоинт"/>

  <sws:annotation-driven/>
```

Если не начнёт работать, то приведи конфиги полностью. Постараемся помочь.

Comment: component-scan указан в файле application-config.xml, я сейчас добавил его в вопрос

Comment: @MikhailBatcer приведи полный `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: Обновил вопрос - добавил

Answer (score 0):

Так вот же ты его пустой и определяешь:

```
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

Убери эту строчку и у тебя будет вместо пустого значения значение по-умолчанию.